# Share Code Between Web Forms in VB.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, visual-studio-2017

Hoping someone can suggest a better way of sharing web form code between pages in a web site application. Using a very basic example to explain, say I have two web pages named "Page1.aspx" and "Page2.aspx" that both have code behind pages named "Page1.aspx.vb" and "Page2.aspx.vb" respectively.

Both pages have a simple button object that performs the same action. Normally you would just add the click event in the code behind for both pages, but what I'd like to do is have it placed once in a shared public class instead.

Html for both pages:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Page1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Page1" %>
<html>
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Page2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Page2" %>
<html>
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
Partial Class Page1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    'I don't want to put the button click event here. How do I reference it from below?
End Class

Partial Class Page2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    'I don't want to put the button click event here. How do I reference it from below?
End Class

Public Class SharedCode
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'I want to put the button click event here.
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.Write("hello")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that the buttons and the code for the buttons are exactly the same. It would be nice to be able to keep the code in one place so you don't have to  repeat the code over and over as well as manage it separately. Especially in scenarios where there are a lot of pages.

One methods I've used that works is to only use ONE code behind page that is shared by both pages:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SharedCode.vb" Inherits="SharedCode" %>
```

Above, for both "Page1.aspx" and "Page2.aspx", instead of using different/specific "CodeFile" and "Inherits" values for each, I use the same code behind page. Then, for code specific to those pages, I add inline `<script runat="server">` tags in each page.

Again, this method works, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a good way of doing that by creating a class which serves as business manager or as "engine" for your pages, both pages can then have their own separated codebehind files and inside the buttonClick event of each button on both pages you do nothing else than call your class, static or not, if class is static like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  SiteEngine.DoWork()

End Sub
```

if SiteEngine class is not static, you jiust have to create an instance of it before calling the DoWork method

this is just one of multiple ways to handle your problem and avoid code duplication which is in most of the cases an unwanted thing to have.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure if this is the solution I'm looking for. I gave a basic example, but this would need to work with something more complex and using web page/form objects, methods, etc... I can't visualize how your approach would do that

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to layered application design.

**Preface**

ASP.NET Web Forms and Visual Studio make it incredibly easy to create applications simply by dragging and dropping controls onto a HTML designer. Accompanying a page, the code-behind file contains all the event handling, data access, and business logic of the application. The **problem** with this approach is that all concerns are mingled, causing problems for testing and resulting in a duplication of business logic because it is difficult to reuse logic that is intrinsically tied to a particular view (ASPX page). Sometimes this is called the *Smart UI antipattern*.

**Separating Your Concerns**

An antidote to the Smart UI antipattern is the notion of layering your application. Layering an application is a form of separation of concerns and **can be achieved via** namespaces, folders, or with separate projects. The following is the bare minimum and overly simplified but you get the idea:

1. Create a new blank solution in Visual Studio and name it `MyWebSite`.
2. Add a new class library project to the solution by right-clicking the solution name and selecting Add > New Project. Name the new project `MyWebSite.Presentation`. Delete the `Class1.vb` created by default.
3. Add a new web application to the project by selecting Add > New Project and selecting the Web Application Project. Name the project `MyWebSite.Web` and set it as the StartUp Project (by right-clicking on it).
4. Right-click on the `MyWebSite.Web` project and add a project reference to the `MyWebSite.Presentation` project.

Your layered project structure is now complete.

Add a new class to the **presentation** project and name it `Presenter`:

```
Public Class Presenter
    Public Function Display() As String
        Return "hello"
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, in the button click event handler(s) in your ASPX page(s) you can write:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim presenter As New Presentation.Presenter

    Response.Write(presenter.Display)
End Sub
```

Again, this sample is rather simplistic but will get you started with how to separate your code into layers. I chose to separate the layers into projects; however, using folders or namespaces is just as effective.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Only question, why do they need to be in two different "projects" withing the same "solution". I need to play around with it more, but this makes sense to me. Thank you for the time and great explanation.

Comment: @ptownbro As said, they don't need to. You can have all the code in one project (e.g. the web application) and organize it using folders (or namespaces). It is a matter of taste but it also depends on the size and complexity of the project,if you ask me. Nevertheless, organizing the code into layers is a must when it comes to code reuse and maintenance and you can only benefit from it in all but very small projects.